# How file locking and package managers work in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

Today I encountered a "Text file busy" error when trying to overwrite a running program I made with a newer version.

I thought that UNIX like systems don't automatically lock up running files, so package managers like `apt` can upgrade those software, even if they are running services.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Unix-like_systems

Am I wrong in my understanding?
My environment is Ubuntu, and I use the XFS filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

The Text file busy error in specific is about trying to modify an executable while it is executing. The "Text" here refers to the fact that the file being modified is the text segment for a running program. apt can change file but not edit it

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure I understand the difference between changes and editing as you call it. I would think that normally when software is upgraded with a new version, the contents of that file would be new.
How does apt etc. replace the file that is the entity of the running process?

Comment: can replace the file but not  change content of the file.

Comment: I may be misleading you, but I am not trying to open the memory of a running program or its files in a binary editor and rewrite its contents.

I am only trying to create a new version of the executable in a different location from the running executable, and overwrite it by copying the file to the old executable that is running.

Comment: oh, in that case the error is really strange

Comment: The canonical way is to create file.new, delete file, rename file.new to file.

Comment: where is located you file?

Comment: @stark Thank you. It looks like I was able to replace the file with your method.

Comment: @TaronQalashyan Both the old and new files are under the home folder, but both files are on different machines, and I was trying to copy them with `scp`.